# Call Fabric directly in Python

Tags: python, fabric

I want to extend Fabric with some functionality and would like to call Fabric programmatically.

What I figured out is to call the `main()` method in https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/main.py, but I can't pass any parameters directly to the function, because it reads it's parameters within the function.

Any idea to set the command line parameters programmatically and the calling `main()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `execute` method in the `Fabric` library to call tasks.

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/api/core/tasks.html?highlight=execute#fabric.tasks.execute

Answer (score 3):

You should read the [Library use documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/library.html), as it'll likely explain how to do what you're attempting.